# Get frames of camera streams in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, camera, core-video

I am currently developing an application for a research project, and the goal is to develop something that takes three live camera streams, and output one live video stream with those three camera streams interleaved.

The first step is to get three video camera streams frame by frame. I've never dealt with any video frameworks in Cocoa before and I'm pretty confused as to how to synchronize these three steams. Ideally, I would be able to have a buffer of frames, and I can just loop through three of them at a time to process three frames from each camera.

Could anyone give me some reference/documentation on relevant frameworks that help me do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I do some R&D and find some helpful material for you may it will helps you:

**1)**  http://erikrothoff.com/2011/07/capturing-a-photo-programmatically-with-objective-c-using-qtkit/

**2)**  [QTKit Application Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/QTKitApplicationProgrammingGuide/UsingQTKit/UsingQTKit.html)

**3)**  [GPUImageVideoCamera Class Reference](http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/GPUImage/0.1.0/Classes/GPUImageVideoCamera.html)

**4)**  http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/324339-how-to-capture-video-stream.html

**5)**  [AV Foundation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/04_MediaCapture.html)

Hopefully this info will helps you.